# Apache Tika: Parsing a text file omits last part?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I am trying to parse a plain text file using Tika but getting inconsistent
behavior.

More specifically, I have defined a simple handler as follows:

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
     @Override
     public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
     {
        System.out.println(new String(ch));
     }
}
```

Then, I parse the file ("**myfile.txt**") as follows:

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ContentHandler handler = new MyHandler();

Parser parser = new TXTParser();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

String mimeType = tika.detect(is);
metadata.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);

tikaParser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);
```

I would expect all the text in the file to be printed out on screen, but a
small part in the end is not. More specifically, the **characters()** callback
keeps reading 4,096 characters per callback but in the end it apparently
leaves out the last 5,083 characters of this particular file (which is a few
MB long), so it even goes beyond missing the last callback.

Also, testing on another, small file, which is about 5,000 characters long,
no callback seems to take place!

The MIME type is correctly detected as **text/plain** in both cases.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to put together a small JUnit unit test that shows the problem? There are several unit tests for Text parsing in Tika which all parse, so clearly another one is needed for your case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Tika are you using? Looking at the source code it reads chunks of `4096` bytes which can be seen on line `129` of [TXTParser](http://search-lucene.com/c/Tika:/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/TXTParser.java%7C%7C+%2522plain+not%2522). At line `132` the `characters(...)` routine is invoked.

In short, the target code is:

```
   char[] buffer = new char[4096];
   int n = reader.read(buffer);
   while (n != -1) {
       xhtml.characters(buffer, 0, n);
       n = reader.read(buffer);
   }
```

where `reader` is a `BufferedReader`. I cannot see any flaw in this code, hence I'm thinking you might be working an older version?

Comment: I can't see any flaw with the above code, either, but the issue remains. Very strange!